# Neural Networks in C

Tags: performance, c, neural-network

This block of code is one of my first C header files I have made; it's ported from a Python program I made a few months ago for a project.

I was just looking for advice on how to increase the efficiency of the program. I tried to make everything as efficient as possible, but am I missing anything? Also, any suggestions to improve my programming in general are greatly appreciated!

```
/*
Neural networks library

By Ben Jones
1/13/2017
*/

#ifndef NEURAL_NETWORKS_INCLUDED
#define NEURAL_NETWORKS_INCLUDED

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct neuron_struct neuron;

struct neuron_struct {
    float *weights;
    float *dw;
    float db;
    float neuron_error;
    unsigned int numinputs;
    unsigned int numoutputs;
    unsigned int inputindex;
    float lastout;
    float bias;
    float error;
    unsigned int *inpneurons;
    unsigned int *outneurons;
    float *inputs;
};

neuron *create_neuron(float *weights, unsigned int numweights){
    static neuron output;
    output.dw = malloc(sizeof(float)*numweights);
    output.weights = malloc(sizeof(float)*numweights);
    output.inputs = malloc(sizeof(float)*numweights);
    output.numinputs = numweights;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numweights; i++){
        output.weights[i] = weights[i];
        output.dw[i] = 0;
    }
    return &output;
}

void free_neuron(neuron *n){
    free(n->dw);
    free(n->weights);
    free(n->inputs);
}

float neuron_eval(neuron *n, float *inputs){
    float sum = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n->numinputs; i++){
        sum += inputs[i]*n->weights[i];
        n->inputs[i] = inputs[i];
    }
    sum += n->bias;
    n->lastout = 1/(1+exp(-sum));
    return n->lastout;
}

void neuron_teach(neuron *n, float u, float m){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n->numinputs; i++){
        n->dw[i] = n->inputs[i]*n->neuron_error*u + m*n->dw[i];
        n->weights[i] -= n->dw[i];
    }
    n->db = n->neuron_error*u + m*n->db;
    n->bias -= n->db;
}

void neuron_random_weights(neuron *n, float lower, float upper){
    float rand_flt;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n->numinputs; i++){
        rand_flt = ((float) rand())/RAND_MAX;
        rand_flt *= upper-lower;
        rand_flt += lower;
        n->weights[i] = rand_flt;
    }
}

typedef struct layer_struct layer;

struct layer_struct{
    neuron *neurons;
    unsigned int numneurons;
    unsigned int numweights;
    float *outputs;
    float *errors;
};

layer *create_layer(float *weights, unsigned int numweights, unsigned int numneurons){
    static layer output;
    output.neurons = malloc(sizeof(neuron)*numneurons);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numneurons; i++){
        output.neurons[i] = *create_neuron(weights, numweights);
    }
    output.numneurons = numneurons;
    output.numweights = numweights;
    output.outputs = malloc(sizeof(float)*numneurons);
    output.errors = malloc(sizeof(float)*numneurons);
    return &output;
}

void free_layer(layer *l){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < l->numneurons; i++){
        free_neuron(l->neurons+i);
    }
    free(l->neurons);
    free(l->outputs);
    free(l->errors);
}

void layer_eval(layer *l, float *inputs){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < l->numneurons; i++){
        l->outputs[i] = neuron_eval(l->neurons+i, inputs);
    }
}

void layer_teach(layer *l, float u, float m){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < l->numneurons; i++){
        neuron_teach(l->neurons+i, u, m);
    }
}

void layer_calc_errors(layer *l){
    int i;
    int j;
    float sum;
    for(i = 0; i < l->neurons[0].numinputs; i++){
        sum = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < l->numneurons; j++){
            sum += l->neurons[j].weights[i]*(l->neurons[j].neuron_error);
        }
        l->errors[i] = sum;
    }
}

void layer_random_weights(layer *l, float lower, float upper){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < l->numneurons; i++){
        neuron_random_weights(l->neurons+i, lower, upper);
    }
}

typedef struct feed_forward_struct feed_forward;

struct feed_forward_struct{
    layer *layers;
    unsigned int numlayers;
    unsigned int maxlayersize;
    float *outputs;
    float *inputs;
    float *errors;
};

feed_forward *create_feed_forward(unsigned int *layers, unsigned int numlayers){
    static feed_forward output;
    output.numlayers = numlayers;
    output.layers = malloc(sizeof(layer)*numlayers);
    output.maxlayersize = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numlayers; i++){
        if(layers[i] > output.maxlayersize){
            output.maxlayersize = layers[i];
        }
    }
    float *weights = malloc(sizeof(float)*output.maxlayersize);
    for(i = 0; i < output.maxlayersize; i++){
        weights[i] = 0;
    }
    float lastnumneurons = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < numlayers; i++){
        output.layers[i] = *create_layer(weights, lastnumneurons, layers[i]);
        lastnumneurons = layers[i];
    }
    free(weights);
    output.outputs = malloc(sizeof(float)*(output.layers[output.numlayers-1].numneurons));
    output.inputs = malloc(sizeof(float)*(output.layers[0].numneurons));
    output.errors = malloc(sizeof(float)*(output.layers[output.numlayers-1].numneurons));
    return &output;
}

void free_feed_forward(feed_forward *ff){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < ff->numlayers; i++){
        free_layer(ff->layers+i);
    }
    free(ff->layers);
    free(ff->outputs);
    free(ff->inputs);
    free(ff->errors);
}

void feed_forward_eval(feed_forward *ff, float *inputs){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < ff->layers[0].numneurons; i++){
        ff->inputs[i] = neuron_eval(ff->layers[0].neurons+i, inputs+i);
    }
    layer_eval(ff->layers+1, ff->inputs);
    if(ff->numlayers > 2){
        for(i = 2; i < ff->numlayers; i++){
            layer_eval(ff->layers+i, ff->layers[i-1].outputs);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < ff->layers[ff->numlayers-1].numneurons; i++){
        ff->outputs[i] = ff->layers[ff->numlayers-1].outputs[i];
    }
}

void feed_forward_teach(feed_forward *ff, float *inputs, float *expected, float u, float m){
    feed_forward_eval(ff, inputs);
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i = 0; i < ff->layers[ff->numlayers-1].numneurons; i++){
        ff->errors[i] = ff->outputs[i] - expected[i];
    }
    for(i = ff->numlayers-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(i == ff->numlayers-1){
            for(j = 0; j < ff->layers[i].numneurons; j++){
                ff->layers[i].neurons[j].neuron_error = ff->errors[j]*(ff->layers[i].neurons[j].lastout)*(1-ff->layers[i].neurons[j].lastout);
            }
        } else {
            for(j = 0; j < ff->layers[i].numneurons; j++){
                ff->layers[i].neurons[j].neuron_error = ff->layers[i+1].errors[j]*(ff->layers[i].neurons[j].lastout)*(1-ff->layers[i].neurons[j].lastout);
            }
        }
        layer_calc_errors(ff->layers+i);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < ff->numlayers; i++){
        layer_teach(ff->layers+i, u, m);
    }
}

void feed_forward_random_weights(feed_forward *ff, float lower, float upper){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < ff->numlayers; i++){
        layer_random_weights(ff->layers+i, lower, upper);
    }
}

typedef struct network_struct network;

struct network_struct{
    neuron *neurons;
    unsigned int numneurons;
    bool *nextupdates;
    unsigned int **net;
    unsigned int *numoutputs;
};

network *create_network(unsigned int **net, unsigned int *numoutputs, unsigned int numneurons){
    static network output;
    output = (network){.net = net, .numneurons = numneurons, .numoutputs = numoutputs, .neurons = malloc(sizeof(neuron)*numneurons), .nextupdates = malloc(sizeof(bool)*numneurons)};
    int i;
    int j;

    for(i = 0; i < numneurons; i++){
        output.neurons[i]=(neuron){.lastout = 0, .outneurons = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*numoutputs[i]), .numinputs = 0, .inputindex = 0};
        output.neurons[i].numoutputs = numoutputs[i];
        output.nextupdates[i] = false;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < numneurons; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < numoutputs[i]; j++){
            output.neurons[i].outneurons[j] = net[i][j];
            output.neurons[net[i][j]].numinputs += 1;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < numneurons; i++){
        output.neurons[i].inpneurons = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*output.neurons[i].numinputs);
        output.neurons[i].weights = malloc(sizeof(float)*output.neurons[i].numinputs);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < numneurons; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < numoutputs[i]; j++){
            output.neurons[net[i][j]].inpneurons[output.neurons[net[i][j]].inputindex] = i;
        }
    }
    return &output;
}

void network_set_output(network *n, unsigned int neuron, float output){
    n->neurons[neuron].lastout = output;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n->neurons[neuron].numoutputs; i++){
        n->nextupdates[n->neurons[neuron].outneurons[i]] = true;
    }
}

void network_step(network *n, unsigned int iterations){
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    for(i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
        static bool *new_nextupdates;
        new_nextupdates = malloc(sizeof(bool)*n->numneurons);

        for(j = 0; j < n->numneurons; j++){
            new_nextupdates[j] = false;
        }

        for(j = 0; j < n->numneurons; j++){
            if(n->nextupdates[j]){
                n->nextupdates[j] = false;
                float inps[n->neurons[j].numinputs];
                for(k = 0; k < n->neurons[j].numinputs; k++){
                    inps[k] = n->neurons[n->neurons[j].inpneurons[k]].lastout;
                }
                neuron_eval(&(n->neurons[j]), inps);
                for(k = 0; k < n->numoutputs[j]; k++){
                    new_nextupdates[n->neurons[j].outneurons[k]] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        free(n->nextupdates);
        n->nextupdates = new_nextupdates;
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Nice clean code!

Comment: Why did you implement that all in the h file?

Comment: Because I wanted to make a C library. Don't worry, I made an actual header file after the second answer-er told me putting all of that in a header file doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must say your code is really clean and easy to read. The naming is very good and coherent, you should consider answering questions here.

Now, enough for the compliments, now my suggestions:

in `create_feed_forward` you could use `calloc` which zeroes the memory way faster that you could do with a loop

```
float *weights = calloc(output.maxlayersize,sizeof(float));
```

in `feed_forward_teach` you'd make core more readable by declaring a pointer on `ff->layers[i]` and use that in the inner loop.
Performance-wise, maybe the optimizer could do it, but it's more readable, and cannot be slower:

```
for(i = ff->numlayers-1; i >= 0; i--){
    layer *lay_i = ff->layers+i;
    if(i == ff->numlayers-1){
        for(j = 0; j < ff->layers[i].numneurons; j++){
            lay_i->neurons[j].neuron_error = ff->errors[j]*(lay_i->neurons[j].lastout)*(1-lay_i->neurons[j].lastout);
        }
    } else {
        for(j = 0; j < ff->layers[i].numneurons; j++){
            lay_i->neurons[j].neuron_error = ff->layers[i+1].errors[j]*(lay_i->neurons[j].lastout)*(1-lay_i->neurons[j].lastout);
        }
    }
```

in `create_network` you could initialize `output.neuron[i]` in one line instead of two:

```
    output.neurons[i]=(neuron){.lastout = 0, .outneurons = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*numoutputs[i]), .numinputs = 0, .inputindex = 0, .numoutputs = numoutputs[i]};
```

in `network_step`, you allocate the block for `new_nextupdates`, same remark as `create_feed_forward`: use `calloc`, and remove the `static` qualifier, which is useless.

```
    bool *new_nextupdates = calloc(n->numneurons,sizeof(bool));
```

Aside from that the code could benefit from some comments. There are currently none in your code.

Of course, use `-O2` or `-O3` optimization flags when compiling, and consider running your code through a profiler to identify the parts to hammer on in priority.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks nice, but is see a few issues in it which I'll try to list here:

- This is supposedly a header file. However, you've included in here both declarations and definitions of your functions and structures. Normally, only the structures and the declarations of the functions should go into the header file, while the definitions of the functions should go into a source file (a .c). The way it is done at the moment, if you try to include your file into two different compilations units, you will have a problem at link time for multiple definitions of the functions...
- Normally, you define first your structures and typedef them after (or at the same time) but not before. Actually, I'm not sure the way you did it is compliant with the C standard (I could e wrong here).
- You have a potential major issue in the code with the way you allocate your structures: by using a static variable into the "constructors" and returning a pointer to it, you take the risk of storing references to the same structure over and over again. This could lead to tricky bugs and memory leaks. Fortunately, since in the calling side you dereference the pointer returned immediately, you actually store a copy of the structure. But then, why returning pointers in the first place? Just use a local structure for result and return it by value. Complexity-wise, this is the same for the code, but this is safer and cleaner.
- Performance-wise, it is hard to tell anything. Nothing strikes me as problematic, but the good way of doing is to profile your code and possibly optimize the hottest parts when identified.

Comment: For your first point, doesnt the "ifndef NEURAL_NETWORKS_INCLUDED" cover that case?

Comment: No. It only prevents multiple inclusion into a single compilation unit, not across different ones.

Comment: Oh ok, and for the third point, if I'm understanding you correctly, thus conflicts with the actual reaults of running tests; I have successfully taught neural networks xor, which wouldn't work if all of the neurons were referencing the same structure.

Comment: Ok, I re-read the code and indeed, it works as you dereference your pointer from the calling side. But then, just return your structures by value, not reference. I'll fix my answer...

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant now and tested your point, and you're right. For some reason I thought passing back the actual objects would come with a performance hit, but after testing out I can't see any difference in the performance. If I had wanted to pass pointers back from the function, would I have had to dynamically allocate space for the pointers as well?

Comment: Normally, yes, you allocate the pointer into the function and return it. However, since it becomes the caller's responsibility to free it, you have to clearly document that.